# Is Aurora MySQL 1.* reaching end-of-life?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, mysql-5.6

I see the forum discussing the end-of-life process of the Amazon RDS for MySQL 5.6 [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=8790)

I am using Aurora MySQL 1.19.5, which is compatible with MySQL 5.6. Do I need to upgrade it to Aurora MySQL 2.* before Amazon RDS MySQL 5.6 reaches the end-of-life?

Answer (score 1):

Official EOL dates for Aurora MySQL 1.* (MySQL 5.6) will be announced separately, not related to RDS MySQL 5.6 EOL date. Typically AWS give customers 6-months’ notice before moving a database major version to EOL. So my answer to your question is: No, you don't need to upgrade your Aurora instance until AWS announce EOL for Aurora MySQL 1.*